# Python Object as Dictionary Value

Tags: python

So I have the following code in which the value of a dictionary is an object, and the key to that object is an item in the object as such:

```
class MyObject():
    def getName(self):
       return self.name

    def getValue(self):
       return self.value

    def __init__(self,name, value):
       self.name = name
       self.value = value


dict = {}
object = MyObject('foo', 2) //foo is the name, 2 is the value
dict[object.getName()] = object
```

However I cannot access the object like so:

```
>>>print dict['foo'].getValue()
<bound method object.getValue of <__main__.object instance at 0xFOOBAR000 >>
```

Is there a way I can access the object in this manner?

**EDIT:**

I don't know why but my code finally decided to start working, so for anyone haveing similar issues the above code is valid and should work. My current version of Python is 2.7.3

Comment: Yes you can.  Your example works for me.  How does it fail for you?  Do you get an error?

Comment: No error, I am getting `<bound method object.value of <__main__.object instance at {some address}>>`

Comment: Your pasted code has no methods, so that doesn't make sense.  Please post the actual code you are running.

Comment: Your new example makes use of methods that you don't show (like `getName` and `getValue`), so it's hard to know for sure what's up.  My guess would be that you want to do `object.getName()` and `object.getValue()` (note the parentheses).

Comment: Now it should be fully updated to reflect the nature of the types of calls I am making.

Comment: Next time, please make sure the code you give is a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/) - otherwise it is incredibly hard to help (and it shows effort to solve it yourself).

Answer (score 15):

You always need to include parentheses when calling functions, so write:

```
dict['foo'].getValue()
```

Also, the `getValue` method should accept a `self` parameter and access instance attributes through it:

```
def getValue(self):
    return self.value
```

Finally, that programming style, where every attribute is accompanied by a "getter", is discouraged in Python. It is [easy enough](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) to implement calculated slots, so there is no need for getters.

Names such as `dict` and `object` are also highly discouraged because they conflict with [built-in types](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html) of the same name.

**EDIT**
The code was edited in the meantime, rendering some of the above remarks obsolete. The latest version of the posted code appears to work just fine when pasted into Python.

Comment: This isn't an issue with syntax I can't copy and paste the code so I have to shorthand bits of it. The key in my code works properly and it returns the proper address of object I am attempting to access however that is all it returns.

Comment: @Blackninja543: You need to copy and paste the code.  If you "shorthand" it and your "shorthand" gives different errors, then no one can help you.  To understand what is wrong in the code you are using, we have to see the actual code you are using.  Your pasted code has a syntax error because you're using `//` for comments instead of `#`.

Comment: @Blackninja543 When I paste your latest code into Python, and type `dict['foo'].getValue()`, it prints `2`, so it works now.